# Is My Solar System Plausible?

Tags: science-based, orbital-mechanics, solar-system, astrophysics

I have been working on and off on a worldbuilding project/speculative evolution project I want to document this Solar System's history from the beginning and essentially go into way more detail than necessary.
So I will provide a basic overview of this systems planets.

My question is simple. Does this work? Am I overlooking something massive? are the orbits unstable? does something not make any sense? I'm essentially just asking for final thoughts, suggestions and even fixing if something is just widely wrong and couldn't work, before I finalize everything and move on. How much, if any "Hand Wavium" would be required?

### The Star(s)

To begin with my system is a binary system of a F0V and a K - Type star
see this older question for more details: [F type and K type Star Binary](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/254444/f-type-and-k-type-star-binary/254454#254454)

So to summarize, I ended up placing the K star at about 55 AU from the Primary star to get a more stable orbit than my original 5.5AU orbit. Big thanks to "M.A Golding" for that answer.

#### F Type

- Luminosity: 1.63L
- Radius:1.04  *solar radii*
- Surface Temperature: 6242K
- Lifetime: ~7.3 Billion Years

#### K Type

- Luminosity:0.21L
- Radius: 0.629
- Surface Temperature: ~5200K
- Lifetime: ??? (Didn't bother calculating since its stupidly long anyways)

### The Planets

I haven't figured names for them yet (at least cool original ones) So all Inner planets are given A and then a number like A1, A2, etc. All outer planets are given B1, B2, etc. "outer" meaning across the frost line.

#### Planet A1

This is a Super Mercury type planet orbiting the main star at around 0.373 AU. Making its Orbital Period 2.57 Months, The planet has no Atmosphere to speak of and is heavily cratered
(all in earth masses and earth radius)

Basic Stats:

- Mass = 0.47
- Radius = 0.766
- Density = 5.76 g/cm^3
- Day Length = 121 days (Tidally Locked)
- Surface Gravity = 7.86 m/s^2
- Semi Major Axis = 0.373 AU
- Pericenter = 0.366 AU
- Apocenter = 0.381 AU
- Eccentricity = 0.0195
- Inclination = 2.82°
- Tilt = 2.20°
- Orbital Period = 2.57 Months

#### Planet A2

Planet A2 is the largest of the inner planets, With an average temperature planet wide of 119F orbiting closely to the star, with an orbital period of 5.57 months. its surface features are that of a hot dry dusty desert with some volcanic activity.

- Mass = 1.60
- Radius = 1.17
- Density = 5.56 g/cm^3
- Day Length = 35.8 Hours
- Atmospheric Pressure = 0.202 Bars
- Surface Gravity = 11.5 m/s^2
- Semi Major Axis = 0.624 AU
- Pericenter = 0.622 AU
- Apocenter = 0.626 AU
- Eccentricity = 0.00328
- Inclination = 1.76°
- Tilt = 11.7°
- Orbital Period = 5.57 Months

#### Planet A3

Basically a "sister planet" to planet A2 despite being significantly smaller, it has similar surface features and composition Due to more green houses gasses it is actually hotter than planet A2 Despite being further away from the sun. Somewhat Venus like situation. with the thickest atmosphere of the inner planets. its atmosphere is predominantly CO2, and SO2 with some Nitrogen.

- Mass = 0.75
- Radius = 0.918
- Density = 5.35 g/cm^3
- Day Length = 10.3 Days
- Atmospheric Pressure -- 2.48 Bars
- Surface Gravity = 8.74 m/s^2
- Semi Major Axis = 0.873 AU
- Pericenter =  0.87 AU
- Apocenter = 0.877 AU
- Eccentricity = 0.00406
- Inclination = 3.41°
- Tilt = 41.2°
- Orbital Period = 9.21 Months

#### Main Planet

Obviously the main planet of the system and the 4th from its star, the one with life (when I get around to that part).

- Mass = 1.20
- Radius = 1.09
- Density = 5.10 g/cm^3
- Day Length = 27 hours
- Atmospheric Pressure = 1.13 Bars
- Surface Gravity = 9.92 m/s^2
- Semi Major Axis = 1.22 AU
- Pericenter =  1.20 AU
- Apocenter = 1.24 AU
- Eccentricity = 0.0165
- Inclination = 3.21°
- Tilt = 24.5°
- Orbital Period = 1.27 Years (465 Earth Days)

#### Planet B1

The First Gas Giant in this system, it is very large being slightly less massive than Jupiter but larger in radius.
(This planet is in Jupiter M and Jupiter Radii)

- Mass = 0.845
- Radius = 1.40
- Density = 1.10 g/cm^3
- Day Length = 3.26 Hours
- Surface Gravity = 30.0 m/s^2
- Semi Major Axis = 7.13 AU
- Pericenter = 7.06 AU
- Apocenter = 7.19 AU
- Eccentricity = 0.00886
- Inclination = 6.74°
- Tilt = 39.0°
- Orbital Period = 17.9 Years

#### Planet B2

This gas giant is under half the mass of Jupiter:

- Mass = 0.42
- Radius = 10.0 R Earth
- Density = 0.734 g/cm^3
- Day Length = 24.6 hours
- Surface Gravity = 13.1 m/s^2
- Semi Major Axis = 12.7 AU
- Pericenter = 12.2 AU
- Apocenter = 13.1 AU
- Eccentricity = 0.0357
- Inclination = 2.19°
- Tilt = 19.3°
- Orbital Period = 42.3 Years

#### Planet B3

Due to its proximity to the K type star, it orbits with a higher eccentrically and extreme inclination. its also an ICE Giant. And, is extremely small for an ice giant.

- Mass = 4.59 M Earth
- Radius = 5.86 R Earth
- Density = 0.129 g/cm^3
- Day Length = 19.1 days
- Surface Gravity = 1.34 m/s^2
- Semi Major Axis = 18.1 AU
- Pericenter = 15.0 AU
- Apocenter = 21.2 AU
- Eccentricity = 0.171
- Inclination = 42.7°
- Tilt = 57.4°
- Orbital Period = 72.6 Years

#### Planet B4

This ice giant was stolen from the main star and now orbits the secondary star in a very inclined slightly unstable orbit.
(For Orbits and stuff remember it orbits the K star not the primary)

- Mass = 26.7 M Earth
- Radius = 7.84 R Earth
- Density = 0.305 g/cm^3
- Day Length = 20.7 days
- Surface Gravity 4.26 m/s^2
- Semi Major Axis = 12.0 AU
- Pericenter = 8.47 AU
- Apocenter = 15.4 AU
- Eccentricity = 0.291
- Inclination = 38.5°
- Tilt = 66.5°
- Orbital Period = 48.6 Years

#### Planet C1

These "C" Planets are inner planets that orbit the K type star.

- Mass = 0.21 M Earth
- Radius = 0.553 R Earth
- Density = 6.86 g/cm^3
- Day Length = 12 Hours
- Atmospheric Pressure = 2.51 Bars
- Surface Gravity = 6.76 m/s^2
- Semi Major Axis = 0.376 AU
- Pericenter = 0.372 AU
- Apocenter = 0.441 AU
- Eccentricity = 0.0857
- Inclination = 0.0223°
- Tilt = 51.9°
- Orbital Period = 3.65 Months

#### Planet C2

Other than the "main planet" this one is the second most suitable for life it has small shallow seas splotched across its surface, and a decent atmosphere, however the seas are acidic and relatively new to the planets surface having only existed for a few million years.

- Mass = 1.25 M Earth
- Radius = 1.06 R Earth
- Density = 5.79 g/cm^3
- Day Length = 60 hours
- Atmospheric Pressure = 1.19 Bars
- Surface Gravity = 10.9 m/s^2
- Semi Major Axis = 0.635 AU
- Pericenter = 0.621 AU
- Apocenter = 0.65 AU
- Eccentricity = 0.0224
- Inclination = 0.0474°
- Tilt = 6.94°
- Orbital Period = 7.14 Months

So again if anything seems off, or wouldn't work please let me know. Hell if none of this works let me know.

Comment: The semi-major axis is one half of the major axis. The major axis is the sum of the peri- and apo-center; so for example for planet C1, pericenter + apocenter = 0.372 + 0.441 = 0.813, which divided by 2 is 0.401, not 0.376 as given in the question. So that there is no point is asking about subtle stuff when the setup fails basic arithmetic.

Comment: P.S. Please check that the semi-major axes and orbital periods obey Kepler's [Third Law of Planetary Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler's_laws_of_planetary_motion): the squares of the orbital periods should be in the same proportion as the cubes of the semi-major axes. (That is, once you have set the semi-major axes of the orbits and the orbital period of any one planet, the orbital periods of the other planets orbiting the same primary should be computable.)

Comment: This is a pretty broad question (read: it's a lot of questions rolled into one). It might be worth the $30 to buy a copy of [Universe Sandbox](https://universesandbox.com/), which would give you more flexibility and faster answers than the Q&A of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @AlexP um thats just a typo since I had last minute decided to change the eccentricity a bit since I left it at 0 for some reason. Also that was kind of the point of the question, If something doesn't make sense tell me so I can fix it. So thanks I forgot abt that and will now edit that. And saying "It fails Basic arithmetic" just feels well insulting? considering that was THE ONLY planet with a wrong Semi Major axis correct me if I'm wrong -_-.

Comment: @JBH Is it really that broad? really? I just asked if my system was plausible and gave out all the information I thought would be useful? SURE I DID GIVE TOO MUCH, but I just added brief descriptions of the planets incase anyone was curious ALL I WAS asking was if this system made any sense. And yes this is tested and working in UE2 and has been stable for 71,800 years of in game time. I ask because I trust the word of you guys over a game.

Comment: @Dono I'm an electrical engineer with a strong science background. YES! It's a LOT! Analyzing each of those characteristics both for individual celestial body compliance and the interrelationship with all other bodies is enormous! Had you asked if a circuit of that complexity was realistic, I'd be telling you to run it through SPICE. If the simulation says it's reasonable, run with it. Any detail outside the game's capability (which is *considerable*) is irrelevant in a story context. It helps if you understand that the goal of this site is suspension of disbelief, NOT real life perfect.

Comment: Typo? These data should come from an Excel or LibreOffice Calc or Google Sheets table and should never be typed in by hand. And Universe Sandbox is easily the most sophisticated generally available numerical integrator for N-body problems. If it says that the system is fine from the point of view of gravitational interactions then it is fne from the point of view of gravitational interactions. It is extremely unlikely that a reader will have access to a more sophisticated simulator and will take the time to actually use it...

Comment: @JBH ok thats fair if I think I have checked off suspension of disbelief. Realism always been my number one goal and this part was something I was trying to get down. Thanks for feedback much appreciated.

Comment: @AlexP wdym never typed in by hand? Its kind of impossible not too. And yes they were from a list I compiled previously I simply placed in the wrong information its really not that big of a deal… If UE2 is acceptable then I of course will use it! Thanks for the comment(s) I think Im going to move onto the last part of this astronomy part now.